# Screen flickering in random intervals, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, display

My screen started to flicker/blip randomly every minute or so (sometimes it is multiple flicks in couple of seconds).

I've tried reinstalling graphic drivers and also Ubuntu on Wayland as per other answers that I've found but without any effect.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on Dell Latitude 5590. My graphic card is Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07).

Does anyone have any advice for this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Two things, have you tried another DE (for instance LXDE), and have you ensured that it is a software issue and not a physical issue? My laptop screen flickers too, but it's just a loose connection in the backlight which happens when the screen is in certain positions.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to check whether the display would still flickers with the fresh installation and it still does. So I suppose it is a hardware issue.